# Android-Code to Implement PDF Viewer

Tags: android, pdf

Here i need to use Pdf-Viewer in my app.i took many API as a reference but still stucking up in viewing Pdf files from SDCARD. here my code

`**First.java**

```
public class First extends ListActivity {
String[] pdflist;
File[] imagelist;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
        }
    });
    pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
        pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
    }
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
    openPdfIntent(path);
}
private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
    try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
        intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

**Second.java**

```
public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity {

@Override
public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return R.drawable.left_arrow;
}

@Override
public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return R.drawable.right_arrow;
}

@Override
public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return R.drawable.zoom_in;
}

@Override
public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return R.drawable.zoom_out;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return R.layout.pdf_file_password;  
    }

@Override
public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return R.id.etPassword;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return R.id.btOK;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return R.id.btExit;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return R.id.pagenum_edit;
}}
```

And i used [Android-Pdf-Reader-Library](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library) project.in my emulator Dialogue as"Loading pdf file" is appearing after clicking on Pdf files. And Can you anyone tell me how to Change the Pdf pages by swiping with finger??

Comment: Did you find any solution for curl/flip pages with using this library?!

Answer (score 0):

you can open pdf on google doc

```
    WebView webviewer = new WebView(this);
    webviewer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webviewer.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    setContentView(webviewer);

    webviewer.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=PDF_url/fileName.pdf");
    setContentView(webviewer);
```

To open the PDF in application like quick pdf or adobe pdf reader:

```
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for immediate reply.In my app i don't need to open PDF in WebView bro. Help me to open PDF in above Code.

Comment: if you dont want to open on webview simply open on readers using 2nd code which i gave u.

Comment: I have tried that too.what shuld i want to give as a parameter(file) in Uri path?

Comment: You have to give path where your pdf file saved in your sd card.
final File file = new File(  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()      +"mypdf.pdf");

Comment: @furqi...Thnks its working perfectly..is it will open the Hyperlink in   the PDF pages??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) library.

**Add this dependency in your Grade:**

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

**Add PDFView in activity_main.xml**

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Add Load a PDF file in MainActivity.java**

```
pdfView.fromUri(Uri)
```

or

```
pdfView.fromFile(File)
```

or

```
pdfView.fromBytes(byte[])
```

or

```
pdfView.fromStream(InputStream) // stream is written to bytearray - native code cannot use Java Streams
```

or

```
pdfView.fromSource(DocumentSource)
```

or

```
pdfView.fromAsset(String)
    .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) // all pages are displayed by default
    .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
    .swipeHorizontal(false)
    .enableDoubletap(true)
    .defaultPage(0)
    // allows to draw something on the current page, usually visible in the middle of the screen
    .onDraw(onDrawListener)
    // allows to draw something on all pages, separately for every page. Called only for visible pages
    .onDrawAll(onDrawListener)
    .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener) // called after document is loaded and starts to be rendered
    .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
    .onPageScroll(onPageScrollListener)
    .onError(onErrorListener)
    .onPageError(onPageErrorListener)
    .onRender(onRenderListener) // called after document is rendered for the first time
    // called on single tap, return true if handled, false to toggle scroll handle visibility
    .onTap(onTapListener)
    .onLongPress(onLongPressListener)
    .enableAnnotationRendering(false) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
    .password(null)
    .scrollHandle(null)
    .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
    // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
    .spacing(0)
    .autoSpacing(false) // add dynamic spacing to fit each page on its own on the screen
    .linkHandler(DefaultLinkHandler)
    .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH) // mode to fit pages in the view
    .fitEachPage(false) // fit each page to the view, else smaller pages are scaled relative to largest page.
    .pageSnap(false) // snap pages to screen boundaries
    .pageFling(false) // make a fling change only a single page like ViewPager
    .nightMode(false) // toggle night mode
    .load();
```

**If you are using ProGuard**, don't forget to add below line:

```
-keep class com.shockwave.**
```